# Disable copy(ctrl+c), paste(ctrl+v),cut(ctrl+x) in excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

I have developed the vsto template in C# in which,i have added data validation for many fields in the excel sheet.If the user copy paste the content, those validations rules are overwrites and does not work. **how can i restrict user to copy,paste,cut.**Is there any **other way to overcome this problem?**

Comment: See this source http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=84495

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried protecting the workbook ?
Two ways to do the same

1.)[manually](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/spreadsheet_protection_faq1/)

2.)[programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7czw9wzs.aspx)

Comment: In certain cases, user might want to add data in cells but wish to keep it paste protected. Protecting is not a way to Disable paste operation.

Answer (score 2):

Following code should intercept Ctrl+V and effectively disable it

1.To disable the Paste Option(ctrl + v )

```
Application.OnKey("^v", "");
```

2.To enable the Paste Option(ctrl + v ) again

```
Application.OnKey("^v", Type.Missing);
```

Comment: -1 rep: this stops only intercepting indeed, doesn't answer the question to stop even Mouse copy/paste actions.

Comment: @Skuta :-( Rep :Right click menu for the excel application can be easily disabled i guess.....

Comment: Thank Sangram for you text. 
I was problem with 64bitExcel automation with Windows 10
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391337.
Solution was Show Excel before open file and close after open method, but when user at this moment use ctrl + V , your solution works for me at this case.

Comment: @IrqMishell Glad that answer is still relevant after 10 years :)