# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT) when opening xlsx file

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have this exception that is driving me crazy.

When I try to open a .xlsx file this way

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
string v = "path\File.xlsx";
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(v); //This triggers the exception
app.Visible = true;
Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[1];
```

I have this exception

```
Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105): Server launches an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object 
at MainWindow.loadFile(String v) in MainWindow.cs:line 139
```

Anyone could give me a solution and why is this happening?

Ps: I'm using Interop library to open Excel.

Edit: Apparently if I set 
`app.Visible = true;` it works, but I don't want that the Excel window appears.

Comment: What is `v`? Can you post the exact contents of that variable?

Comment: v is the path to the file

Comment: Sounds like an error in Excel itself coming back through COM. What happens if you open the file in Excel manually?

Comment: Nothing unusual, if i open the file manually it just opens

Comment: Did you manage to find a more elegant solution for this issue?

Comment: No, I have no solution to this issue. I've just left it unsolved and hope won't appear again...

Answer (score 3):

```
 appExcel.Visible = true;
            classeur = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(DB_Path, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            appExcel.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Will check it and see if it works because I still have this problem.

Comment: I voted this up because it worked for me - but i do not like this solution at all... Why does this work? can it be done any other way i wonder?

Comment: I become this error after update windows 10 patch 1709 on January 2019. Earlier Excel works without setting visible true.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't find solution but when I use workaround from abdosup, Excel window was show for tiny moment and there was dangerous that user in open workbook moment press ctrl+v key loading could crash.

Please look at:

```
appExcel.Visible = true;
OldExcelTop = appExcel.Top;
appExcel.Top = 10000;
appExcel.OnKey("^v", "");
classeur = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(DB_Path, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
appExcel.Visible = false;
appExcel.OnKey("^v", Type.Missing);
appExcel.Top = OldExcelTop ;
```

i found this solution in
[Disable copy(ctrl+c), paste(ctrl+v),cut(ctrl+x) in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825664)